# Convert ngx_chain_t into buffer memory

Tags: c, nginx

I'm looking for the way to convert ngx_chain_t object (with is already filled by nginx and ready response to client or pass to another filter) to buffer memory just like when we read the whole file into memory like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX 999999

char source[MAX + 1];
FILE *fp = fopen("thisfile", "r");
size_t newLen = fread(source, sizeof(char), MAX, fp);
source[++newLen] = '\0';
```

Now **source** is buffer memory that hold the whole content of **thisfile** in memory.

Is there any way to convert ngx_chain_t buffer into something likes **source** in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Try fmemopen(3), read the man page 1st!

Maybe I did not  understand the question.

But as I understood it, it was about replacing the fopen into something else the could  read the inx_chain_t object structure like:

```
  ...
  fp = fmemopen(object, MAX, "r");
  newLen = fread(source, sizeof(char), MAX, fp);
  ...
```

Sorry if this still is a misunderstanding.

Comment: do you actually know what I asked?